# Shopware 5: distinguish between transactions from different platforms

Tags: shopware

I have a shopware 5 store connected to amazon, ebay or cdiscount. I can use shopware's API to get orders, order details etc.
How can I distinguish between these orders based on what platform they came from? So far I haven't found any field in the resources to get this detail.

Answer (score 0):

That heavily depends on the plugins that connect your shop to these platforms. I assume these plugins either provide a custom API or none to check that. Maybe they set an attribute or set an internal comment. In general shopware is not aware of orders comming from somewhere else but the shopware checkout itself. So there is no default field for this information.

From my experience I know that amazon only exposes an anonymized email address from the customer that has a common domain like `@marketplace.amazon.com` or `@marketplace.amazon.de`.

Comment: hi, if this helps you - magnalister uses the internal comment field in a shopware order. And thanks!

Comment: Good to know  I haven't had a look into magnalisters code yet